# How to set the star and unstar the image on touchableOpacity in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I need to star and unstar the element in the Flatlist.

Here I have used the Flatlist and renderItem inside the class. Used a constant outsite the class and included in the renderItem.

(i.e)

```
structure.js is like below




 imports...

    const starred =
               <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.log('Long Press')
                      }}
                      delayLongPress={3000}>
                      <FontAwesome5 style={{marginHorizontal: 0}} name="star" size={12} color="#grey"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

    class star extends React.componenet{

    renderItem = ({item}) => {
       return (<Starred onPress= {}
       />)
    }

    render(){
    <Flatlist 
    renderItem= {this.renderItem}
    />   
    }
   }
```

Here how can I setState while onpress in TouchableOpacity here.

Need to change the star to green color onPress

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First there are 2 ways of doing it

1st way : either on every star click you call an api and then update the particular object in array and , the star image is defined by a backend data variable maybe called `isStarred:true`

and if `isStarrted?<ShowStarSelectedImage />:<ShowStarUnSelectedImage />` in your render function

or

by first creating an array of length of flatlist data array, and initially setting like :

```
starArray = ([...Array(sizeOfFlatList).keys()].map(x => 0);) ;
```

And this will create an array of 0 till size of flatlist.

Now on click of star , you can just take its index :

```
onPress = {() => {starArray[index] = 1 // or you can toggle accordingly.}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Can you update the above in any example. Here how the toggle will happens in the const starred

Comment: which method do you want to follow?

Comment: For [1]st one. I will prefer both the above. For my understanding.

Comment: give me some time, ill write the answer